# Wrong results in a longest repeated substring function

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JavaScript function intended to find repeating phrases in a long string. The string is going to be in Unicode and non-English, which stops me from using RegExps. In this 99 bottles of beer example the results should be "bottles of beer on the wall", "take one down, pass it around" etc without numbers, only the recurring parts, but it gives wrong results:

```js
window.findRepeats=function(){
 inputString=document.getElementById("txt1").value;
 
 outputArray=[];
 for(originalStart=0;originalStart<inputString.length;originalStart++){
  for(copyStart=originalStart+1;copyStart<inputString.length;copyStart++){
   if(inputString[originalStart]==inputString[copyStart]){
    for(windowByte=originalStart+1;windowByte<copyStart;windowByte++){
     if(inputString[windowByte]!=inputString[copyStart-originalStart+windowByte]){
      break;
      }
     if(windowByte>originalStart+1){
      outputArray.push([originalStart,windowByte]);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 for(arrayCounter=0;arrayCounter<outputArray.length;arrayCounter++){
  outputArray[arrayCounter]+=":"+inputString.substring(outputArray[arrayCounter][0],outputArray[arrayCounter][1]);
  }
 document.getElementById("txt2").value=outputArray.join("\n");
 }
```

```html
<textarea rows=9 id="txt1">
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall.
98 bottles of beer on the wall, 98 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 97 bottles of beer on the wall.
97 bottles of beer on the wall, 97 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 96 bottles of beer on the wall.
96 bottles of beer on the wall, 96 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 95 bottles of beer on the wall.
95 bottles of beer on the wall, 95 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 94 bottles of beer on the wall.


</textarea>
<br>
    
<textarea rows=9 id="txt2">
    
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="go" onclick='findRepeats()'>
    
</input>
```

If you check out the result, it gives all the repeating substrings but not the longest ones. I want only the longest substrings. As for suffix arrays and trees, I have failed to understand these so far, so I have to deal with this approach.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem. Suffix trees are a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOSO WORKING**

How about this?

Apparently, your original function had an error, something isn't right in the result. I'll attempt to simplify the code now.

```js
window.findRepeats=function(){
  var inputString = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var outputArray=[];
  for(originalStart=0;originalStart<inputString.length;originalStart++){
    for(copyStart=originalStart+1;copyStart<inputString.length;copyStart++){
      if(inputString[originalStart]==inputString[copyStart]){
        for(windowByte=originalStart+1;windowByte<copyStart;windowByte++){
          if(inputString[windowByte]!=inputString[copyStart-originalStart+windowByte]){
            break;
          }
          if(windowByte>originalStart+1){
            outputArray.push([originalStart,windowByte+1]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var shorts = [];
  for(var i=0;i<outputArray.length;i++){
    var curString = inputString.substring(outputArray[i][0],outputArray[i][1]);
    if (curString[0] === " ")
      curString = curString.substr(1);
    if (curString.trim() != "")
      shorts.push(curString);
  }
  var uniq = removeDuplicate(shorts);
  for (var j=uniq.length-1;j>-1;j--){
    for (var k=uniq.length-1;k>-1;k--){
      if (uniq[j].indexOf(uniq[k]) > -1) {
        uniq[k]=uniq[j];
      }
    }
  }
  uniq = removeDuplicate(uniq);
  shorts = uniq;
  document.getElementById("txt2").value=shorts.join("\n----------------\n");
}
function removeDuplicate(arr) {
  return arr.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a > b}).reduce(function(a,b){if (a.slice(-1)[0] !== b) a.push(b);return a;},[]);
}
```

```html
<textarea rows=9 style="width:100%" id="txt1">3 bottles of beer on the wall, 3 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.

1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.

No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.
Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.</textarea>
<br>
    
<textarea rows=9 style="width:100%" id="txt2"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="go" onclick='findRepeats()'>
```

Comment: I have to make myself more clear. The sample input was too short, so I have to correct myself. Take the lyrics of "99 bottles of beer," http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/lyrics.html and run it through the function. I need to have phrases like "bottles of beer on the wall" and "Take one down and pass it around" in the result, all of them, but not their substrings. Sure, that is something more than just one longest substring. Sorry for not making myself enough clear from the beginning.

Comment: @qqqp What you want is what exactly? :/

Comment: There is another piece of code I made for the same purpose, but it is too long and I am afraid nobody here will take the trouble of reading it. [(code)](https://github.com/danielsedoff/regex-replace/blob/f49b8a22e2a030677f6dba9a081654a8823939bd/pstat-new.html) I have tried that approach too, but it also has errors.

Comment: I am editing the question, I see it needs correction.

Comment: This is great, I see you are working on it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielSedoff The code is OK working now, but it seems your original code had an error? Please check result, the "N" in "No more bottles..." isn't there?

Comment: It doesn't do the right thing yet :) This is a hard nut to crack. I add '4 bottles of beer,' and it doesn't find the repeated string 'bottle[s] of beer', only 'bottle[] of beer.' There is something with my initial function, that's right. Thank you for the help. I'll look for other remedies now :)

Comment: @danielsedoff do you need the position of the recursing text?

Comment: No. I need only the recursing text itself and the number of times it is repeated. For example, "bottles of beer on the wall" - 2 times; "bottles of beer" - 2 times; "take one down and pass it around" - 2 times.

Comment: The reason why I made it output the positions is, that the repeating positions show where the output is wrong like: 0,5 hello 1,5 ello 2,5 llo ......

Comment: @I got it simplified. Sorry, your code IS working, it's just because 1 "n" is lowercase and the other "N" is uppercase. You can adapt this code:) I changed the line to `outputArray.push([originalStart,windowByte+1])` and it got fixed

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!